# aws cli to create a table with a time to live specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, ttl

I would like to perform a cli command which creates a table with TTL.

a sample cloud formation/ serverless

```
SampleTBWithTTL:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: SampleTBWithTTL
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: "user_id"
            AttributeType: "N"
          - AttributeName: "name"
            AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: "user_id"
            KeyType: "HASH"
          - AttributeName: "name"
            KeyType: "RANGE"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
          AttributeName: expiration
          Enabled: true
```

so this is what I have so far :

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name sample-tb-with-ttl \
                      --attribute-definitions AttributeName=user_id,AttributeType=N \
                             AttributeName=name,AttributeType=S \
                      --key-schema AttributeName=user_id,KeyType=HASH \
                             AttributeName=name,KeyType=RANGE \
                      --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
```

and what I want/need is to add a TTL/TimeToLive Spec in my aws cli command.

Guys Please help me thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First do this:-

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name sample-tb-with-ttl \
                  --attribute-definitions AttributeName=user_id,AttributeType=N \
                         AttributeName=name,AttributeType=S \
                  --key-schema AttributeName=user_id,KeyType=HASH \
                         AttributeName=name,KeyType=RANGE \
                  --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

Then enable ttl :

```
aws dynamodb update-time-to-live --table-name sample-tb-with-ttl \
                      --time-to-live-specification Enabled=true,AttributeName=expiration
```

Comment: i got this error: Unknown options: --time-to-live-specification, Enabled=true,AttributeName=expiration

Comment: i tried this one and yes this is acceptable but then my problem is that if i run this two commands consecutively. I'll get an error that the Table is still creating and i need to wait for aws to finish the table creation. what i want is to create the table along with the TTL.

Comment: Do i need to create a bash script for that?

Comment: Yes, It is a possible way to create bash script for that.

Comment: okay then ill accept your answer my problem now is to create a bash script that waits the creation of dynamodb table then execute the update-time-to-live. @Deep do you know how to do it?